# Proper logic for looping through user controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, loops, user-controls, repeater

I have a dynamic webpage that loads a user control multiple times, including loading the user control within itself as many times as needed. Within the user control there are four controls: Title Label, Repeater, Placeholder and within Repeater a AjaxControlToolkit Rating control.

The structure can look like the following:

```
Webpage
  Placeholder
    UserControl (repeater hidden, no data)
      Placeholder - [UserControl]
        UserControl
          Repeater
            RepeaterItem - [RatingControl]
            RepeaterItem - [RatingControl]
          Placeholder - [UserControl]
            UserControl (placeholder hidden, no data)
              Repeater
                RepeaterItem - [RatingControl]
                RepeaterItem - [RatingControl]
    UserControl
      Repeater
        RepeaterItem - [RatingControl]
        RepeaterItem - [RatingControl]
      Placeholder - [UserControl]
        UserControl (placeholder hidden, no data)          
          Repeater
            RepeaterItem - [RatingControl]
```

**Here is my recursive method:**

```
Protected Sub Get_Ratings(ByVal ctl As Control, ByVal grouptotal As Integer)
    If TypeOf ctl Is PerformanceEvaluationSubcontractorControl Then
        Dim pesctl As Control
        For Each pesctl In ctl.Controls
            If TypeOf pesctl Is PerformanceEvaluationSubcontractorControl Then
                Me.Get_Ratings(pesctl, grouptotal)
            ElseIf pesctl.Controls.Count > 0 Then
                Dim spesctl As Control
                For Each spesctl In pesctl.Controls
                    If TypeOf spesctl Is Repeater Then
                        Dim rptctl As Control
                        For Each rptctl In spesctl.Controls
                            Me.Get_Ratings(pesctl, grouptotal)
                        Next
                    End If
                    If TypeOf spesctl Is PlaceHolder Then
                        Dim plhctl As Control
                        For Each plhctl In spesctl.Controls
                            Me.Get_Ratings(plhctl, grouptotal)
                        Next
                    End If
                Next
            ElseIf TypeOf pesctl Is AjaxControlToolkit.Rating Then
                Dim ajrating As AjaxControlToolkit.Rating = pesctl
                grouptotal = grouptotal + ajrating.CurrentRating
            End If
        Next
    ElseIf ctl.Controls.Count > 0 Then
        Dim sctl As Control
        For Each sctl In ctl.Controls
            Me.Get_Ratings(sctl, grouptotal)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

My question is, how do I efficiently loop through this type of structure to find the rating controls?

Comment: Yeah that was what I am trying to go for but I cannot figure out the logic of it.

Comment: I tried the recursive but for some reason the repeater items seem to get lost in the shuffle of things.

Comment: You may have other issues, but for sure, you are using the wrong variable in your call to Get_Rating inside your loop of the repeater's controls. You should be passing 'rptctl', but instead you are passing 'pesctl' (copy-paste error, I would think).

Comment: Yeah I know about my issues LOL, anyway, I notice what you are saying about the rptctl, makes sense. The beginning of the method is wrong too because it relies on the ctl being either the user control or the count of the passed ctl to be larger than 0. I am just super confused about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my VB.NET isn't all that great, but wouldn't a recursive function look similar to:

```
Protected Function GetRatings(ByVal control As Control) As IEnumerable(Of AjaxControlToolkit.Rating)
  If (control.Controls.Count > 0) Then
    Dim result As New List(Of AjaxControlToolkit.Rating)()

    For Each child In Control.Controls
      Dim rating As AjaxControlToolkit.Rating = child As AjaxControlToolkit.Rating
      If Not (rating Is Nothing) Then
        result.Add(rating)
      Else
        result.AddRange(GetRatings(child))
      End If  
    Next

    Return result
  Else
    Return Enumerable.Empty(Of AjaxControlToolkit.Rating)()
  End If
End Function
```

Couldn't you then do a summation:

```
Dim controls As IEnumerable(Of AjaxControlToolkit.Rating) = GetRatings(control)
Dim total As Int32 = Enumerable.Sum(Of AjaxControlToolkit.Rating)(_
    controls, Function(rating) rating.CurrentRating)
```

If the syntax is way off, let me know, I don't normally do VB.NET

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I am going to try this and let you know, it looks proper to me

Answer (score 0):

The code below works perfectly for my needs. I did not test the AjaxControlToolkit.Rating type.

Call the sub with

```
 getcontrols(Page.Controls)
```

Here is the sub

```
 Sub getcontrols(ByVal obControls As ControlCollection)
    Dim sContent As String = ""

    For Each childcontrol As Control In obControls

        If childcontrol.HasControls Then
            setcontent(childcontrol.Controls)
        End If

        If childcontrol.GetType() Is GetType(AjaxControlToolkit.Rating) Then

            Dim sID = CType(childcontrol, AjaxControlToolkit.Rating).ID
            'DO SOMETHING

        End If
    Next 
End Sub
```